# Why am I unable to send e-mail with Thunderbird - the connection times out, trying to connect

Tags: server, email, thunderbird

I am running Ubuntu 21.04 and regularly updated. I have 100mb fiber connection and the time of day when trying to send an e-mail does not matter. I can, however, successfully send a message using a different computer and e-mail client. I attempt to send, and the SMTP connection times out, unable to connect. The service is Zitomedia.net and the port is 587 and I have checked my settings and all seems to be proper.
Additionally, the Ubuntu Software repository provides two apparently different versions of the Thunderbird client software, with no indication which might be better than the other.
[image: screen shot of SMTP settings]

Comment: The reason for two versions is simple - one is a snap and the other is a deb. You *could* try the opposite to what you have already installed (they can co-exist).

Comment: Go to https://support.zitomedia.net/email/tbird.htm and check your smtp settings.

Comment: @heynnema The website of support.zitomedia.net (that you linked) uses TLS 1.0 (and additionally has expired certificate) while Firefox in Ubuntu requires TLS 1.2 and therefore it cannot connect. It may be the same case for their SMTP server and Thunderbird.

Comment: @raj makes a point. The zitomedia support web site has a TLS problem. Go to their website using the computer where email works, get the settings, and check this computer. If the settings are correct, contact zitomedia support for more help.

Comment: To the first respondent, I did attempt the other variety of Thunderbird, and was utterly unable to use it. While installing, an attempt to retrieve certificate failed, and no further progress was possible. I uninstalled, powered-down, restarted and then re-installed the client called "Thunderbird Mail". This version re-installed and works except for being able to send mail. I am not knowledgeable enough to understand the difference between deb and snap. Am still learning, but do not always know what to ask or how. Thank you, all the same.

Comment: @heynnema I tried `openssl s_client -connect mail.zitomedia.net:587 -starttls smtp` and it properly connects using TLS 1.2 and a valid certificate. So only the website has an issue. To the OP: did you use `zitomedia.net` or `mail.zitomedia.net` in Thunderbird setup as the SMTP server? Because it should be the latter.

Comment: @tomkoehler The difference between deb and snap is mostly about how it's packaged and delivered. When there's a choice, I prefer to use the deb version, as it has less impact on the system. Edit your question and show us a screenshot of your smtp settings. Have you gone to the support site yet? Do the settings match between the two computers?

Comment: I tried to connect to support.zitomedia.net/email/tbird.htm and failed. I have checked my settings, and they are correct, to the best of my understanding. Certificates and security seem to be the stumbling blocks. My outgoing SMTP setting is mail.zitomedia.net and port 587. My authentication is "normal password"

Comment: @tomkoehler What is security set for?

Comment: I tried the Terminal code raj used, and apparently connected.
To heynnema, the security is SSL/TLS yes.

Comment: @tomkoehler Try STARTTLS and see if that helps.

Comment: I have sent an e-mail inquiry to Zito, via gmail, which works for me. The company has some notoriety, none good. Waiting, now to see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments...

Changing the SMTP server security from **SSL/TLS** to **STARTTLS** solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am satisfied that my question...my problem...has been answered and solved. heynnema's solution, to use STARTTLS is working for me. Thank you to all who responded and worked on this, for me. –
tom koehler